# Is it possible to setup and switch multiple wired IEEE802.1X authentication profiles in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, lan, wired, ieee802.1x

In Windows 7, I use two IEEE802.1X wired network authentitication settings which I have to change by hand, since every time I switch the configuration, the old one is lost. (In Linux this is trivially handled by the wpa-supplicant)

Comment: I know nothing about IEEE802.1X authentication, but I guess it's stored in the registry. I'd use a monitoring tool like Procmon to see what the changes are between the two settings, and create two batch files to change between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a script-based solution which exploits the `netsh` utility in windows 7.

Firstly i used `netsh lan export profile folder=<folder>` for both 802.1 profiles (I manually set up the first, then exported its settings, then repeated the same for the second, etc), thus I got one XML file for each profile.

Then I wrote a simple script for each of them (have to be run as administrator)

```
chcp 1250
netsh lan add profile filename="<folder>\profile1.xml" interface="Local Area Network"
PAUSE
```

provided that the script file has the Windows cp1250 encoding and the network interface has name `Local Area Network`.

The interface name can be determined by running:

```
netsh lan show interfaces
```